# Troubleshooting 'Invalid Property' Error in Azure Data Factory Dataflow

Tags: azure, join, azure-web-app-service, azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I have a data flow, and it's throwing the following error. Any idea how to fix it?

[image]

Join Activity

[image]

Dataflow
[image]

Comment: Could you please verify the connection strings outside of the dataflow, and check if the connections are build properly? Apart from that, check the values from the column Bill to customer name.